# How to compute gradients to implement deepfool using tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am implementing deepfool using tensorflow, but I do not know how to calculate the gradients, so I hope if you could help me work it out.
the source code file is in https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JEiIidq8sNi03aliHFaYEESjDu87O6Tv?usp=sharing

```
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        fs = model(x)
        loss_value = loss_func(one_hot_label_0, fs)
    grad_orig = tape.gradient(fs[0, I[0]], x)
```

I have changed the arguments of tape.gradient() several times, but useless.

```
def loss_func(labels, logits):
        return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)

    while k_i == label and loop_i < max_iter:

        pert = np.inf

        one_hot_label_0 = tf.one_hot(label, num_classes)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(x)
            fs = model(x)
            loss_value = loss_func(one_hot_label_0, fs)
        grad_orig = tape.gradient(fs[0, I[0]], x)

        for k in range(1, num_classes):
            one_hot_label_k = tf.one_hot(I[k], num_classes)
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                tape.watch(x)
                fs = model(x)
                loss_value = loss_func(one_hot_label_k, fs)
            cur_grad = tape.gradient(fs[0, I[k]], x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate why the gradient computation is not working? Do you have a stack trace?

[Here's an example](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/c8054c23d643de1a63c778627c0b25158ae495f4/cleverhans/future/tf2/attacks/fast_gradient_method.py#L66) of a gradient computation performed as part of the fast gradient method implementation in CleverHans. You might also want to look at the [PGD implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/c8054c23d643de1a63c778627c0b25158ae495f4/cleverhans/future/tf2/attacks/projected_gradient_descent.py#L10), which calls the fast gradient method in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First many thanks to 'idol' Nicolas, Merci beaucoup. Here I define the loss_func as follows.

```
def loss_func(logits, I, k): 
    # return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)
    return logits[0, I[k]]
... 
loss_value = loss_func(fs, I, 0)
grad_orig = tape.gradient(loss_value, x)
```

Then I can calculate the gradient normally. I have two obvious discoveries, one is the attack is model-dependent since different model gets different attack samples with the same image; the other one is that many attacks to the mnist dataset are perceptible since most images changed a lot, but I do find samples with few changes as reported in the paper. However, I am not sure what I did is as the way in the deepfool paper, especially the gradient.